# How to remove namespace prefixes from JSON response in CXF/JAX-RS?

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, cxfrs

I have the following response created by CXF using JAX-RS:

```
{"ns1.CustomerInformationResponse":{
  "@xsi.type":"ns1:CustomerInformationResponse",
  "ns2.code":"SUCCESS",
  "ns1.customer":{
    "@xsi.type":"ns2:CustomerBaseDTO",
    "ns2.login":"login1"
  }
}}
```

And here is the relevant portion of my current context configuration:

```
<jaxrs:server address="http://${host}:${port}/rest/customer">
  <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="customerManagementServiceImpl" />
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  <jaxrs:providers>
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AegisJSONProvider" />
  </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I would like to receive responses like the one above, without the namespace prefixes (i.e. ns1, ns2, etc...).

I have tried to add `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.transform.TransformOutInterceptor` to `cxf:outInterceptors`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 3):

In your beans.xml, you can specife the bean jsonProvider like below.

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AegisJSONProvider">
<property name="ignoreNamespaces" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Now Invoke the jsonProvider in the Context Configuration as below

```
<jaxrs:server address="http://${host}:${port}/rest/customer">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="customerManagementServiceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean ="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: Additionally, you may use the `attributesToElements` property to remove the `@` characters added on for the JSON properties created from XML attributes.

Comment: I think the best solution i found on net after searching for hours.. thanks guys.